# Criar user usando uma function

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, oracle, funções, oracle11c

alguém poderia me ajudar, ela fica dando erro quando salvo '-'

Erro(19,5): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "CREATE" when expecting one of the following:     ( começar case declare sair for goto if loop mod nulo pragma    raise retornar selecionar atualizar while com             << continuar fechar atual deletar    fetch lock insert aberto rollback savepoint set sql executar    commit forall intercalar pipe expurgar

```
create or replace
FUNCTION   FC_CRIA_USUARIO_SADP(USERN IN VARCHAR2)
RETURN VARCHAR2 
iS
RES VARCHAR2;
bd varchar2;

BEGIN
MSG:='NULL';

  select USERNAME INTO RES FROM DBA_USERS 
  WHERE USERNNAME = USERN; 
  SELECT name into bd FROM V$DATABASE;


  IF RES IS NULL THEN   


  CREATE USER USERN IDENTIFIED BY 12345678;
  GRANT CREATE SESSION TO USERN;
  GRANT RL_SADP_USUARIO TO USERN;
  GRANT RL_ACESSO_CONSULTA TO USERN;

  MSG:= 'Usuário ' || USERN ||' criado no banco' ||bd;

RETURN MSG;

  ELSE
  MSG:= 'Usuário ' || USERN ||' já existe no banco' ||bd;


END IF;
END FC_CRIA_USUARIO_SADP;
```

Comment: Acho que DDL não pode ser feito em PLSQL , creio que a solução é rodar via execute immediate vide Sample DDL Operation Using Native Dynamic SQL   em    https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96590/adg09dyn.htm

Answer (score 1):

Altere para o descrito abaixo:

```
execute_immediate('CREATE USER USERN IDENTIFIED BY 12345678');
execute_immediate('GRANT CREATE SESSION TO USERN');
execute_immediate('GRANT RL_SADP_USUARIO TO USERN');
execute_immediate('GRANT RL_ACESSO_CONSULTA TO USERN');
```

Só não me lembro se é necessário o ";" no final de cada execução. Também é necessário o usuário conectado ter os direitos para criar usuários.

Nota: Talvez seja melhor e mais seguro ao invés de criar um usuário no banco, criar uma tabela de usuários com senhas e criptografia, e deixar a aplicação fazer a autenticação, se o foco for inserir usuários para utilização em sistemas, pois colocando no banco, estes usuários podem modificar o banco sem precisar de um sistema, o que é 
potencialmente perigoso